# pyinstaller and --onefile: excluding a .py file

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have an application that I distribute using pyinstaller with the --onefile flag so that it is neater (even though unpacking it takes a bit of time).

I would like to leave a function accessible to the end user in a file called, say, `user.py`. If I run pyinstaller with `--onefile` and `--exclude-module user`, the resulting executable doesn't seem to be able to run my local copy of `user.py`.

Is this possible?

I didn't get any traction on this question, so I figured I'd add some more detail.

Eg. I made three files:

main.py

```
try:
    from otherfile import getresponse
except ImportError:
    from packagedfile import getresponse

resp = getresponse()
print(resp)
```

packagedfile.py

```
def getresponse():
    return "Response in packaged file"
```

otherfile.py

```
def getresponse():
    return "Response in other file"
```

When I run this (`python main.py`) with all three files in the same dir, it prints `response in other file`. When I compile with pyinstaller (`pyinstaller main.py`) I get the same response. When I compile with pyinstaller as `pyinstaller --exclude-module otherfile main.py` and put otherfile.py in the same directory, I get the same response. When I compile with pyinstaller as `pyinstaller --exclude-module otherfile --onefile main.py`, I get 'Response in packaged file' when otherfile.py is in the same directory as the .exe file.

Comment: My hack solution for this was to use `subprocess` to execute a script inside of a helper function with a combination of command line arguments and a file that I save/open/save/open to pass data from the pyinstaller-ed program and the script I want to keep outside and open. Definitely a hack.

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: Windows 10 (Python 3.7.x)

Comment: then you need to use a semi colon instead. Updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
pyinstaller --exclude-module otherfile --add-data otherfile;. main.py
```

Comment: Hmm. Any variant I tried of this returned `pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: [thing I tried to add]`